# How do I store dynamic radio button input in a MySQL database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, radio-button

I know how to store *static* radio buttons (where the names do not change) but what about where the name is dynamically taken from a database.

Example: The control

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
$var = array(
    'db_column_name' => $this->input->post('radio_btn_name')
);
$this->model_name->function_name($var);
```

The view

```
echo form_radio('radio_btn_name','myValue', false);
```

Ok but what about this Example: The view

```
echo form_open('control/form_event');
foreach ($query as $q) :
echo form_label($q['label_from_db'],$q['name_from_db']);
echo form_radio($q['name_from_db'],$q['value_from_db'], false);
endforeach;
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
```

How would I write the controller fro the *dynamic* radio button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whenever you really wanna use radio buttons or checkboxes. Radio buttons are really simple if all use the same `name=""`. If they don't, then they're pointless.

This example assumes that you use checkboxes instead:

```
$arr_where = array('id' => $int_id); // The id for the row you wish to update

$arr_values = array();

$arr_fields = array('radio_name1', 'radio_name2', 'radio_name3');
foreach($arr_fields as $h)
    if ($this->input>post($h))
        $arr_values[$h] = 'TRUE'; // Or whatever you wish to store
    else $arr_values[$h] = 'FALSE'; // Or whatever you wish to store

if ($arr_values)
    $this->db->update('table_name', $arr_values, $arr_where);
```